# Open URLs in New Chrome Window

Tags: google-chrome

I decide to open a url in a new window with command:

```
$ open -na 'Google Chrome' 'https://www.etymonline.com/'
```

It opened a new window in blank.

Comment: If you need to open a url In an existing tab... I think it's not possible using bash directly. [You can with applescript](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34966581/603568). You can trigger applescript from bash if needed.

Comment: I've updated my answer to use an alternate solution that you might find useful, please have a look.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to use the `--args` *option*, e.g.:

```
open -na 'Google Chrome' --args --new-window 'https://www.etymonline.com/'
```

From the manual page for the [**open**](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/open.1.html) *command*:

> **--args**
>   All remaining arguments are passed to the opened application in the argv parameter to main().
>            These arguments are not opened or interpreted by the **open** tool.

---

For more **Google Chrome** *command line switches* that could be added to the `--args` *option* of the `open` *command*, check out the following **URL**.

From: [List of Chromium Command Line Switches](https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/)

> There are lots of command lines which can be used with the Google Chrome browser. Some change behavior of features, others are for debugging or experimenting. This page lists the available switches including their conditions and descriptions.

---

Another approach would be to use **AppleScript** from the *command line*, e.g:

```
osascript -e 'tell application "Google Chrome" to set URL of active tab of (make new window) to "https://www.etymonline.com/"'
```

For ease of use, you could wrap this in a *function* and place it in your `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.profile` file, e.g:

```
openurl () 
{ 
    if [ -n "$1" ]; then
        osascript -e "tell application \"Google Chrome\" to set URL of active tab of (make new window) to  \"$1\""
    else
        printf "\n  Missing URL...\n\n    Syntax: openurl 'URL'\n\n    Example: openurl 'http://www.google.com'\n\n"
    fi
}
```

Then in **Terminal**, simply use the following, e.g.:

```
openurl 'https://www.etymonline.com/'
```

If you execute `openurl` without an *argument*, you get the following output:

```
$ openurl

  Missing URL...

    Syntax: openurl 'URL'

    Example: openurl 'http://www.google.com'

$
```

Note: The **URL** is shown wrapped in single quotes and this to ensure no expansion takes place when the URL is passed to the *function* if it has any *shell special characters* in it. The single quotes can be omitted for basic/simple URLs.

This same approach can be applied to the `open` *command* as well. That said, the reason I'd choose to wrap the **AppleScript** in a *function* is at some point the `open` *command* used in this manner with **Google Chrome** may break. This is because when **Google Chrome** is already open, it's opening a second *instance*, which is then passed to the first *instance* and the second *instance* terminated. This behavior may become problematic as **Goggle Chrome** is updated, where the **AppleScript** in a *function* will not, as it's only talking to the first *instance* of **Google Chrome**.

Comment: It opened one in a new tab.

Comment: @Yumi Tada, I've updated my answer with `--new-window` added to the `--args` _option_. It opens the URL in a new window and it worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

The above answers work from the command line, but if you want Chrome to open things in a new window everywhere by default (and not just from the command-line) you have to change the http/https file handlers to a script that does what you want.

With a default handler set to open a new window, it will work from the command line or when you click a link in Mail or similar, and thus integrate much more nicely with Spaces since you'll get a new window on the current space with your desired link, instead of a new tab in some other Space that you have to hunt for.

Specifically you need a script like this:

```
on open location theURL
    tell application "/Applications/Google Chrome.app"
        make new window
        activate
        set URL of active tab of first window to theURL
    end tell
end open location
```

Then you save that from ScriptEditor as an app, run it to register it with LaunchServices, and edit the ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.LaunchServices/com.apple.launchservices.secure.plist file to have your app as the default for http/https.

You can find an integrated solution with the script as an app and (in a current comment) a PList editing script to tell the system to use your app here:

https://smoove-operator.blogspot.com/2011/06/open-links-from-external-applications.html

Inspiration from http://pepijndevos.nl/2010/05/open-external-links-in-running-browser/ and https://github.com/primalcurve/macsupportpub/blob/master/scripts/setGoogleChromeAsDefaultBrowser_Scrubbed.sh